# Absence of loop is rendering code useless?

Tags: c++

First of all, this is NOT homework. I'm using a book I bought for myself to learn the beginning of C++ at home, and it contains an exercise I'm stuck with. It asks me what is wrong with the following code, but I can't seem to find it. First I thought that it had to do with the fact that there wasn't a while or for loop and thus it couldn't repeat itself rendering the 'i' useless, but I'm not sure if that's the true issue here.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= phrase.size(); ++i)
{
    cout << "Character at position " << i << " is: " << phrase[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Perform the loop by hand and carefully count the number of executions. Then you should get it.

Comment: How do you conclude that there isn't a for loop in this code? And what makes you think the code is useless?

Comment: I forgot that the for loop was a loop of its own. I'm still a beginner in C++, so I didn't notice it very fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition is wrong: `i <= phrase.size()` should be `i < phrase.size()`. Say phrase is a vector of 10 elements. `size()` will return 10, but in last iteration of the loop, `phrase[10]` is accessing an element which isn't there. Dereferencing out of bounds is undefined behaviour, which by C++ standard makes the whole program ill-formed.

Answer (score 1):

```
i < phrase.size()  // Given that you are starting from 0th index, I assume
                   // that the valid array indexes are 0 to N-1
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is the <= size() that is the problem, on the last loop the phrase[i] will actually be one past the end of the array causing a bad reference, so should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < phrase.size(); ++i) 
{ 
    cout << "Character at position " << i << " is: " << phrase[i] << endl; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on this line:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= phrase.size(); ++i)
```

The value of `i` will get at one point equal to `phrase.size()`, which, when indexed later by `phrase[i]` is out of bounds, as indixing in C++ is zero-based.

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly a good guideline to always include the start bound and exclude the last.

So write:

```
for (int i = 0; i < phrase.size(); i++)
```

That way i starts with 0 and ends with the last item.

Answer (score 0):

`<= phrase.size()` should be `< phrase.size()`. The last iteration of the loop will have an `i` equal to `phraze.size()` which is out of bounds since whatever you're iterating starts with an index of `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have 10 items, but counting numbers for them will be look like 0, 1 .., 8, 9. So you should check it by "strictly less" operator.  This fact is confusing first time, but then you will see how is it comfortable.